# Difference between "I'm planning up" and "I'm planning"

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between "I'm planning" and "I'm planning up" when responding to a question about hypothetical plans? Where does this "up" come from?

The context is a conversation between two persons. One of them says that he is "planning up" to begin something in the future, just like "Yes, I'm planning up.". But I assume that he could just say "Yes, I'm planning" and this would have identical meaning.

Update #1: This phrase is from Ozark series:

- Now, be honest. When was the last
  time you were really truly happy?
- Come on. I'm planning up.

Here is a [screenshot of the dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKnur.jpg) from the series.

Update #2:

You may listen to the dialogue at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjihXzVONeE.

Comment: Difference: 'planning' is standard English, 'planning up' is not.

Comment: Even with the dialogue quoted, I have no idea what the reply means.

Comment: @DanGetz it’s clear that the phrase is “I’m planning up”. So the subtitles on the screenshot from my question are correct. I’m still watching this episode so I’ve just double-checked this.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Not a phrase I've ever heard before, and I haven't seen the show.

Comment: I think you (and the subtitler) are miss-hearing "I'm welling up"  meaning "I'm starting to cry" (but I think meant ironically)

Comment: Are you sure the image you have isn't a just an attempt at a meme? The dialogue is transcribed on [Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ozark_(TV_series)), but it doesn't have any lines that remotely resemble "I'm planning": Bruce Liddell: Now be honest, when was the last time you were really truly happy? // Marty Byrde: Oh, come on... come on. // Bruce Liddell: Okay, okay, you got me. You got me. Financial adviser's not my dream job, but I am taking a fucking bite out of the apple.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your attention! I've [uploaded the phrase to YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjihXzVONeE).

Comment: I just listened to clip, I don't know what he's saying, but it isn't "planning up". It is indistinct and said while the other character is speaking. I hear "[something] **out**". Can you tell me what season / episode this is so I can check the script?

Comment: @Astralbee Ozark Season 1 Episode 1. Around 06:20.

Comment: @Astralbee now I think that this could be "I'm planning out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He says "*I'm planning out*".

What he means is he's planning to leave his job.

We sometimes say "out" to mean leave a situation (eg "*I want out*").